# Select com Inner join muito lento

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner

Estou com um problema em que o select está trazendo o resultado certo, mas demorando muito. Segue o select :

```
SELECT c.cod_paciente,
       p.nome,
       i.valor,
       i.quantidade,
       d.convenio,
       c.cod_conta
FROM caddadosclinico d
INNER JOIN cadcontapct c ON d.cod_paciente = c.cod_paciente
INNER JOIN cadcontitens i ON i.cod_conta = c.cod_conta
INNER JOIN cadmatmed m ON i.cod_matmed = m.cod_matmed
INNER JOIN cadpaciente p ON p.cod_paciente = c.cod_paciente
WHERE m.grupo = '1'
  AND c.dt_conta_aberta >= STR_TO_DATE('$dt_init', '%d/%m/%Y')
  AND c.dt_conta_aberta <= STR_TO_DATE('$dt_final', '%d/%m/%Y')
GROUP BY c.cod_paciente
ORDER BY p.nome
```

Comment: qual a pergunta?

Comment: preciso otimizar essa consulta

Comment: Sua `query` pode até estar correta, porém, é difícil de saber, pode ser problema de infraestrutura, falta de índice e por ai vai.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cara você pode levar em consideração no seu JOIN também o tamanho de registros de cada tabela e fazer o Join de acordo com isso, por exemplo:

```
TDCUPANT = 900.000 registros
FINAFIM = 300.000 registros
OUTRA_TABELA = 1.000 registros
```

> O seu join deverá começar pelas tabelas menores, ou seja, por
>   `OUTRA_TABELA`, depois `FINAFIM` e por ultimo `TDCUPANT`. Por que isso?

Bem, quando o banco chegar na última tabela do join, grande parte dos registros já estarão separados, filtrados levando menos tempo dentro da tabela com 900.000 registros. 
Claro que no seu caso não ajuda muito, mas deve melhorar um pouco a performance.

Você também pode criar índices para os campos envolvidos no relacionamento, no `[i:19c2cdec39]where[/i:19c2cdec39] e no [i:19c2cdec39]order by[/i:19c2cdec39]`.

> **O que são índices?**

Os índices são, grosseiramente falando, como o índice de um livro. É por ele que o banco de dados se orienta pra encontrar mais rapidamente os registros. Todo banco de dados tem este recurso.

Para se criar índice no Firebird por exemplo faça desta forma:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX NOME_DO_INDEX ON FORNECEDORES (CNPJ,FANTASIA,RAZAO)
```

Aqui, estou criando um índice único com o nome

`[b:b2b8d0c71d]NOME_DO_INDEX[/b:b2b8d0c71d], na tabela [b:b2b8d0c71d]FORNECEDORES [/b:b2b8d0c71d]com os campoas [b:b2b8d0c71d]CNPJ, FANTASIA e RAZAO[/b:b2b8d0c71d]`. Por ser único `([b:b2b8d0c71d]UNIQUE[/b:b2b8d0c71d])` não poderei incluir um fornecedore com o mesmo `[b:b2b8d0c71d]CNPJ, FANTASIA e RAZAO[/b:b2b8d0c71d]` que já exista na base de dados.

Você pode criar quantos índices forem necessários para o seu banco de dados. Mas índice não é só pra esta utilidade. Os índices ajudam a integridade de dados como Checks, Constraints e Foreign Keys. Ajudam na ordenação e etc.

fonte: https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/melhorar-o-desempenho-de-um-select-com-inner-join/31085

Comment: Obrigado, depois de um pouco de trabalho consegui a otimização com a criação de alguns índices e reduzi bastante o tempo de espera.

Comment: boaa! Danilo isso ai

Comment: @DaniloSantos você poderia colocar minha resposta como aceita, afim de finalizar a pergunta ?